# How to prove $\lim_{a\to -\infty} \sup_n P(\sum_1^n X_j / \sqrt{n} \leq a) = 0$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of independent identically distributed $L^2$ random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$. I want to prove that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{a\to -\infty} \sup_n P\left(\frac{\sum_1^n X_j} {\sqrt{n}} \leq a\right) = 0\text{.}
\end{equation}
I get this intuitively, since the distribution of $\sum_1^n X_j/\sqrt{n}$ gets close to the standard normal distribution and $a$ goes to $-\infty$. But how can I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n = \sum_1^n X_j$ and let $a \lt 0$. By Chebyshev's inequality (and using Var$(S_n) = n$):
$$P\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt n}\lt a\right)  = P\left(S_n\lt a\sqrt n \right)$$
$$\le P\left(|S_n|\gt |a|\sqrt n \right) \le \frac{n}{a^2n} = \frac{1}{a^2}$$
Since this is true for all $n$, 
$$\sup_n P\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt n}\lt a\right) \lt \frac{1}{a^2}$$

Now take $\lim$ as ${a\to-\infty}$.

Comment: Actually, I needed to prove the proposition in my question so that I can prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(S_n/\sqrt{n}\leq a)=\int_{-\infty}^a\exp(-t^2/2)dt/\sqrt{2\pi}$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$. So is there a way to solve my question without using this formula? I already proved that the distribution of $S_n/\sqrt{n}$ converges vaguely to the standard normal distribution $\nu_0^1$, so I'm free to use this fact.

Comment: @zxcv Well I just realized I didn't need CLT at all, just Chebyshev's inequality.